# Turning the string 7.3M into bytes using BASH commands

Tags: bash

I am trying to find files based on a parameter that can take in values such as 7.4M but from what it seems I cannot use:

```sh
FileSize=7.4M
find . -size $FileSize
```

doing this results in a "illegal trailing character"

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use [**bitwise operation**](http://unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/116305-shell-script-convert-file_size-bytes-megabytes.html)

```
FileSize=7
find . -size $(( FileSize << 20 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the "M" (you might already know this) but the 7.4. The numeric value must be an integer followed by an optional scaling value. The following should work:

```
FileSize=7400k
find . -size $FileSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that normalize your input to integer:

```
normalize() { echo "$1" | awk -FM '/M/ { printf "%dk", $1*1024 }; !/M/ { print $1 }'; }
```

After defining this function, you use it like this:

```
$ echo $(normalize 7.4M)
7577k
$ echo $(normalize 15k)
15k
```

So you could write your code like this:

```
find . -size $(normalize $FileSize)
```

But I would recommend against it anyway. Doing such syntactic sugar in bash is tricky and is a recipe for little bugs. For example, the user of normalize() would maybe expect that "15.5k" would work, but it doesn't. Also, the user could expect that 7.4M wasn't rounded by this function, but it is (indeed there is no way a file can be *exactly* 7.4mb, because 7.4mb = 7759462.4 bytes).

It's better to follow find's syntax, like chepner suggested.

Also, for most cases you probably should use something like

```
find . -size +7M -and -size -8M
```

To find files in an interval (in this example, between 7mb and 8mb). Without a + or a - in the beginning, it will find only files with this exact size. But as I said, there is no file that is exactly 7.4mb; you probably got this size from a program that reported an approximated value.